# Get page title and inner image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, get, title

I have a javascript, which takes a link with specific id and put the image to this links from that page.

```
$('#link').each(function(){ 
    var c=$(this),
        o=c.parent(),
        url=this.href,
        m='/images/no-img.jpg'; 

    $.get(url,function(d){
      var s=m; 
      var b=$(d).find('.post-text img')||false; 
      if(b){ 
         for(var i=0,j=b.length;i<j;i++){ 
           if(!/(ucoz.net|download.png)/i.test(b[i].src)){ 
             s=b[i].src; 
             break; 
           } 
        } 
      } 
      o.prepend('<img src="'+s+'" />); 
    }); 
});
```

I want to add the page name from div, but not the page title.

**For example**

This is a link on a page1.html:

```
<a id="link" href="/page2.html">page2</a>
```

This is how page2.html looks like

```
<body>
<div class="title">Page name 2</div>
<div class="post-text">
<img src="/img.jpg" />
This is a post text.
</div>
</body>
```

I need to get "Page name 2" from div with class "title" and to have such result on a page1.html:

```
<img src="/page2/img.jpg" /><a id="link" href="/page2.html">Page name 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use the same id for different elements, id must be unique

Answer that we have reached after discussion

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').each(function()
    {
        var _this = $(this);
        var href = _this.attr('href');

        $.get(
            href,
            function(data)
            {
                var html = $(data);
                var titleNode = html.find('.title');
                var imageNodes = html.find('.post-text img');
                imageNodes = imageNodes.filter(function()
                {
                    return !$(this).attr('src').match(/ucoz\.net|download\.png/i);
                });

                if (imageNodes.length)
                {
                    var src = imageNodes.first().attr('src');

                    if (/.+\..+\//.test(src))
                    {
                        var imageSrc = src;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageSrc = href.replace(/\.html$/, ''); // remove .html from href="/page2.html"
                        imageSrc += '/';
                        imageSrc += src.replace(/^\//, '') // remove first / to avoid //
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    imageSrc = '/images/no-img.jpg';
                }

                _this.html(titleNode.text());
                _this.before('<img src="' + imageSrc + '">');
            }
        );
    });
});
```